How do I use Google Chat API with Python [Windows]?
I am trying to make a simple birthday app for Google chat.
The logic is pretty simple:

Create a list of all employees from an xls file
Create another list for employees with upcoming birthdays (in the next 20 days)
For each employee with an upcoming birthday, create another list with all of the other employees and assign a random person to collect money and gift ideas

That's what I've done so far, if you want more details I can share the repo. The difficult part is the next one:

For each employee with an upcoming birthday, create a Google Chat space with all other people from the team and display something like "Employee X has a birthday on dd-mm, employee Y is responsible for the organization".
Delete the space after X's birthday has passed.

Now, I did create a Google Cloud account, enabled APIs, got credentials (I have a JSON file and an API key), but I really don't know where to go from here. I did a lot of reading in the Google documentation, but I'm really lost, I would appreciate a more dummy-friendly step by step guidance.
I wrote the Python logic, but I cannot implement the API part.
Thank you in advance!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
